# Japan, USA and the new Asian Infrastructure Investment Bank

Tags: international-relations, economy, geopolitics

Why is Japan not part of the new AIIB? Why are countries like the United States, France or Germany are against it?

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia says:

> proposed by the government of China

Somehow, I find it unsurprising that China's arch-opponent wasn't playing ball

Further reasons:

> ... regarded by some as a rival for the IMF, the World Bank and the Asian Development Bank (ADB), **which are regarded as dominated by developed countries like the United States**

Wikipedia article also pretty clearly states the official explanations from Japan and US for why it ain't their club

> The United States' officials have expressed concerns about whether the AIIB would have high standards of governance, and whether it would have environmental and social safeguards.
>
> "Japan is dubious about whether (the AIIB) would be properly governed or whether it would damage other creditors"